# Wordpress: Exporting month and year of post into custom meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, field, custom-fields

I would like to save publish date of regular Wordpress post into custom meta fields. Is there any way how to write function based on scenario below?

Demanded scenario:
When I save/create post, some function will take current month and year and than save these data into custom meta fields named custom_month and custom_year.
Every post will have these custom meta fields with month and year separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to this effect:

```
function hook_save_post($post_id, $post, $update) {
    //Check it's not an auto save routine
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;
    
    //Perform permission checks! For example:
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
            return;
    
    // Remove this save_post action in case modifications are made in this process
    remove_action('save_post', 'hook_save_post', 13);
    
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    
    switch ($post_type) {
        case 'post':
        case 'page':
            $current_time = (int) current_time('timestamp');
            update_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_month', date('m', $current_time));
            update_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_year', date('Y', $current_time));
            break;
    }
    
    // Return save_post action
    add_action('save_post', 'hook_save_post', 13, 3);
}

add_action('save_post', 'hook_save_post', 13, 3);
```

Comment: The above does for both pages and posts, but if you want it for all post types you can just kill that switch condition or add `default:` after `case 'page':`

Comment: Thank you it works flawlessly. One last question, is there any way how to switch current time for time when the post was published? In case of updated post it will be maybe better.

Comment: well, there are two ways you could do that. If you only want this to save when the post was created you could do a condition on the `$update` parameter which is false for new posts. If you need it to happen on posts that were created before this functionality existed, then you could use `$post->post_date` instead of `$current_time`. Trouble is that this will give you the published date and not the true creation date.

Comment: But, to be honest, if you go the route of `$post->post_date` then you really have no need for the meta data at all.

Comment: I see. The problem is I need to use the values separately because I need to use it in Search & Filter Pro plugin. It doesn't work with the post_date field itself. Anyway thank you very much once again. It helped me a lot.