# Bulk add custom meta data from published date on a large catalog of posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, metadata, custom-fields

I'm looking to follow this post in order to save WP post date data as custom meta for filtering purposes:

[Wordpress: Exporting month and year of post into custom meta field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511972/wordpress-exporting-month-and-year-of-post-into-custom-meta-field)

The problem is I also have a catalog of over 30k existing posts that I'd like to add the same custom meta based on month / year to.  What would be the best way to update existing posts with the new meta fields based on published date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For over 30k post, the fastest and most reliable way to do it is via 2 direct SQL Queries *(via PhpMyAdmin)*, one for the post date YEAR and another one for the post date MONTH.

Always make **a database backup** (or at least in this case, only the `wp_postmeta` table).

> Be sure that your database tables start with `"wp_"`, if not, make the required changes below for `wp_postmeta` and `wp_posts`.

For the year *(the meta key is set to 'published_year')*

```sql
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT p.ID, 'published_year', YEAR(p.post_date)
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE p.post_type = 'post';
```

For the month *(the meta key is set to 'published_month')*:

```sql
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT p.ID, 'published_month', MONTH(p.post_date)
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE p.post_type = 'post';
```

The targeted post type **is only "post"**, so if you want to make it work for pages too (or FOR others custom post types), replace:

```sql
WHERE p.post_type = 'post';
```

with *(comma separated post types)*:

```sql
WHERE p.post_type IN ( 'post', 'page' );
```

---

This can also be done via a function using WPDB class like:

```php
function bulk_add_published_year_custom_meta_data(){
    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) return; // Only for admins
    
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( "
        INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
        SELECT p.ID, 'published_year', YEAR(p.post_date)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        WHERE p.post_type = 'post';
    " );
}

function bulk_add_published_month_custom_meta_data(){
    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) return; // Only for admins
    
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( "
        INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
        SELECT p.ID, 'published_month', MONTH(p.post_date)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        WHERE p.post_type = 'post';
    " );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme.

To run this functions, you can add in functions.php file the following too, one at the time.

First, add:

```php
bulk_add_published_year_custom_meta_data();
```

Save, then browse a page of your website. Remove and save.

Last, add:

```php
bulk_add_published_month_custom_meta_data();
```

Save, then browse a page of your website. Remove and save.

Check that the meta data is set for all posts. Then remove all that code.

You are done.